# Compass / SASS: overwrite attribute?

Tags: compass-sass

I´m working on an existing project that uses compass / sass. In this case, a global (so to speak) `topnavigation.scss` is loaded, which defines a style, which is used for any design / skin we created for our customers.

In that file following mixin is defined:

```
@mixin box-shadow($val...) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $val;
    box-shadow: $val;
}
```

and used like this:

```
.topnavigationHolder {
    // other stuff ...

    @include box-shadow (0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(96, 125, 139, 0.6));

    // other stuff ... 
}
```

Now there´s a customer we created a special design / skin for. The file mentioned above is loaded, but the customers design / skim should NOT show a box-shadow at the `.topnavigationHolder`. Simply adding `box-shadow: none` in "his" .scss, which imports the file mentioned above, does not work.

How can I overwrite the inherited (correct term?) attribute box-shadow?

Comment: Ok, so overwriting should be no problem. I noticed, that any of my changes done are ignored when compiling the .scss.

Comment: Are they loaded in the right order ?